# XML Parsing Error: not well-formed, Redirecting from one page to another

Tags: html, asp.net

Okay so i am doing html/javascript, and there is this button that redirects to another page on my html. However when i click that button, this error showed up

> XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
>
> Location: file:///C:/Users/NP%20Student/Documents/Visual%20Studio%202010/WebSites/WebSite2/Default.aspx
>
> Line Number 1, Column 2:
>
> <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
>
> -^

What is the problem here? Can any kind soul help me out.

Comment: Need to see some code. If anything, this is more an ASP.NET question than a pure HTML question.

Answer (score 0):

If you open a page with non-html-code at the beginning in a browser, the browser doesn't know what he should do (because in your case he doesn't know aspx code) and displays the code itself or throws an error.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a server-side issue and not a client-side one. I haven't heard of a browser that tries to parse content (malformed or not) as XML by default.

Comment: @BoltClock He's reading the site from his local storage and not from a server (That's what I get)

Comment: Oh, blast. Did not notice that. Maybe .aspx files are seen as XML by browsers. To be honest, I haven't worked with ASP.NET in a while so I don't recall what the error messages look like exactly.